# readFileSync not returning buffer when giving dynamic filename but giving result when static filename is given

Tags: node.js

readFileSync is not giving any response if I pass filename dynamic but if I pass it to statically it will give response.

```
function base64_encode(file) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    let bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    return Buffer.from(bitmap).toString('base64');
}

let data_base64 = await base64_encode(process.cwd() + '/public/receipt/' + data.file_name);
```

Comment: put your code in try catch block console the error and execute your return statement if you get readfileSync response and please check the file type you are reading

Answer (score 1):

That code is working well for me. I'd suggest adding some logging to try and understand what is going wrong, I'd add the lines below.

```
const fileName = process.cwd() + '/public/receipt/' + data.file_name;
console.log("File name:", fileName);
console.log("File exists:", require('fs').existsSync(fileName));
console.log("File stat:", require('fs').statSync(fileName));
let data_base64 = await base64_encode(fileName);
console.log("Base64:", data_base64);
```

Comment: Hey, I am still not able to getting response, code you mentioned is giving response like, 
File name: /home/***/public/receipt/jainam@techuz.comw2ev6.pdf
File exists: true
<Buffer >
Base64:

Comment: That's very weird.. can you do a file stat too? Could it be that you don't have read privileges for the file?

Comment: Got the solution actually it is taking time till it binds with readFileSync so I have put timeout and it worked for me.

Comment: Great.. you could consider using readFile with a callback to avoid blocking the main thread. But at least you've fixed the immediate issue!